# driving distance data for multiple point on google maps or other map services

Tags: google-maps, maps

I have four points/places on a google map or other online map; point A,B,C, and D. the only moving point is point A. My question is, is there a way to get the driving distance data from point A to the rest of the points all in one go? it would show data like this; a-b, a-c, a-d. I don't know how to do the API thing? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[How to get total driving distance with Google Maps API V3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251609/how-to-get-total-driving-distance-with-google-maps-api-v3)

Also try using DOM inspector from Firebug... Sometimes it helps allot

Comment: Thanks for the information. I don't know how to do the API developing thing. Do you know if there are site that have these kind of thing. Thanks